# slow xml parsing

Tags: iphone

I am parsing my data from a xml which is generated with php code from a mysql database. I then parse it using NSXMLParser. But the parsing is slow. can some one please help me in finding a faster solution?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBXML parser or libxml2 SAX are much more faster and less memory consuming parsers. The difference is that TBXML cannot parse during download and libxml2 SAX can

Here's the link to compare :[How to choose fastest xml parser for iphone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)